# How to read the Hadoop Sequentil file as an input to the Hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sequence, hadoop-streaming

I have a Sequential file which has the key-value pair of type **"org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable"** , I have to provide this file as the input to the Hadoop job and have to process it in map only. I mean i dont have to do anything which will need reduce.

1) How will i specify the FileInputFormat as SequentialFile ?

2) What will be the signature of map function.

3) How will i get output from map instead of Reduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How will i specify the FileInputFormat as SequentialFile ?

Set the [SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.html) as the input format. Here is the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.java) for the SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat class.

Here is the code

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), getClass());
conf.setInputFormat(SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.class);
```

> 2) What will be the signature of map function.

The map would be invoked with a BytesWritable as key and value types.

> 3) How will i get output from map instead of Reduce?

Set the `mapred.reduce.tasks` property to 0. The output of the map will be the final output of the job.

---

Also, take a look at the [SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat.html). The map would be invoked with Text as key and value types.

Comment: Thank you Praveen, I have used 'job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);' will it make any diffrence? What format would be better performance wise?

Comment: Not sure, but think that SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat is faster than SequenceFileInputFormat. Looked @ the code, but it's a bit complex and will take time to understand it.