# How does hive store sequencefile?

Tags: hadoop, hive

There is a hive internal table which is stored as sequence file, and the first column type is string and the field seperator is '\1',I want to process it using Mapreduce directly, and  find out that the input key is BytesWritable. My question is how hive store data in sequencefile? Is the reason I get bytesWritable key is that the first column type is string? I doesn't configure map's key seperator as '\1', so I am puzzled by the second question

Answer (score 2):

Hive does not treat the first column as a key for a SequenceFile. Rather, the key gets ignored completely. [[1]](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201204.mbox/%3C78CF145F-1AC0-4168-A25B-EADC400F890D@fiksu.com%3E) [[2]](http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/09a7ydw78q/hive-ignores-key-when-reading-sequence-files). So when you are writing your Mapper to operate on a Hive SequenceFile you should also disregard the Key. All of your columns will be part of the Value.

Just in case your Value is also a `BytesWritable` and you want it to be `Text`, try `SequenceFileAsTextInputFormt` ([docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat.html)). The answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818037/how-to-read-the-hadoop-sequentil-file-as-an-input-to-the-hadoop-job) question may help you get set up. You should be able to get a `String` from the `Text` with a simple `toString()`. Your seperator `'\1'` will come in here. Split your `String` on `'\1'` to separate it into your columns from Hive.